# golang html template doesn't display anything

Tags: html, templates, go

I have this code for html/template, and it won't run. I want to display each element in the array and it will return nothing. Please ignore the ioutil file reading.

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age int
}

type Page struct {
    test [3]Person
    test2 string
}

func main() {
    var a [3]Person
    a[0] = Person{Name: "test", Age: 20}
    a[1] = Person{Name: "test", Age: 20}
    a[2] = Person{Name: "test", Age: 20}

    p:= Page{test: a}

    c, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("welcome.html")    
    s := string(c)

    t := template.New("")
    t, _ = t.Parse(s)
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, p)
}
```

and welcome.html:

```
{{range .test}}
    item
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Page.test` field is not exported, it starts with a lowercase letter. The template engine (just like everything else) can only access exported fields.

Change it to:

```
type Page struct {
    Test [3]Person
    Test2 string
}
```

And all the other places where you refer to it, e.g. `p:= Page{Test: a}`. And also in the template:

```
{{range .Test}}
    item
{{end}}
```

**And also: never omit checking errors!** The least you can do is panic:

```
c, err := ioutil.ReadFile("welcome.html") 
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
s := string(c)

t := template.New("")
t, err = t.Parse(s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, p)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Mj1IBgd3il).

Comment: that worked, thank you very much. i actually missed that field exporting thing, where can i read about it?

Comment: @Nickl In the [Language specification: Exported Identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers). The template engine is in a different package (`html/template`), so the rules apply to it too.